# Error creating a new workspace

Tags: linux, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I am trying to create a local workspace so I can map it to VisualStudio online account. Here is the command I am trying to run.

```
tf workspace -new -login:"Windows Live ID"\user,pass -collection:https://shaggyinjun.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

For some reason I am seeing an error. The command does have a `domain/user,pass`. What is this new username and password it is asking me for ?

```
Federated authentication to this server requires a username and password.
```

Apparantly this is issue is caused even when using java clients. Here is what Visual Studio Online has to say for it's questionable behavior.

> **Alternate authentication credentials**
>
> Some applications that work outside the browser (including Team Explorer Everywhere
>   command line client and the git-tf utility) require basic authentication credentials. 
>   Other applications do not properly handle using an e-mail address for the user name 
>   during authentication.
>
> To work with these applications, you need to enable alternate credentials, set a
>   password, and optionally set a secondary user name not in the form of an e-mail address.  > Please note that alternate credentials cannot be used to sign in to the service from a web
>   browser or outside of these applications.

---

Here is another question that I posted and was shot down. Just documenting here for future reference

---

I am able to login using my Visual Studio online credentials via the CLC, but When I try to do the same with a java program, I get an Authentication exception. Is there anything special that needs to be done for Java and / or Visual Studio Online ?

**Java Code**

```
public static final String NATIVE_LIBS_SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory";
public void connect() {
        System.setProperty(NATIVE_LIBS_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, TFS_NATIVE_LIBS_HOME);        

        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Windows Live ID\\user", "password");

        TFSConnection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = new TFSConfigurationServer(new URI("https://shaggyinjun.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"), credentials);
            connection.authenticate();

        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: Authorization failure connecting to 'https://shaggyinjun.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx' (authenticating as Windows Live ID\user)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:709)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:473)
    at ms.ws._LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.connect(_LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.java:384)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:70)
Caused: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSUnauthorizedException: Access denied connecting to TFS server https://shaggyinjun.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as Windows Live ID\venkatram.akkineni@gmail.com)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.LocationExceptionMapper.map(LocationExceptionMapper.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:76)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.connect(LocationService.java:754)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.authenticate(LocationService.java:928)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.authenticate(TFSConnection.java:748)
    at org.netbeans.modules.libswrapper.Installer.restored(Installer.java:54)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadCode(NbInstaller.java:471)
[catch] at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadImpl(NbInstaller.java:394)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.access$000(NbInstaller.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller$1.run(NbInstaller.java:346)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil$2.run(FileUtil.java:447)
    at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:127)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:609)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(FileUtil.java:431)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(FileUtil.java:451)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.load(NbInstaller.java:343)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1194)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1017)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.access$2400(ModuleList.java:118)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList$Listener.stepEnable(ModuleList.java:1409)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList$Listener.access$1400(ModuleList.java:1007)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList$Listener$1.run(ModuleList.java:1231)
    at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:127)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:609)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList$Listener.run(ModuleList.java:1207)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're connecting to visualstudio.com from the cross-platform command line client, you need to set up and use "[alternate credentials](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-eclipse-projects-vs.aspx)".

You cannot use a Microsoft Account (Live ID) because - crazy as it sounds - that only works by supplying passwords to that web page and we cannot rely on a web browsers existence on many platforms.